# Prove or disprove $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ is free

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory, braid-groups

Suppose that $\langle a,b\rangle$, $\langle b,c\rangle$, and $\langle a,c\rangle$ are free, is it true then that $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ is a free group of rank 3? We assume that $a,b,c$ are distinct group elements.

I know this is false if only $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle b,c\rangle$ are free, for example we can take $a=\sigma_1$, $b=\sigma_2$, and $c=\sigma_3$ in the braid group $B_n$ for $n>3$.

Comment: Consider a group with presentation $$\langle a,b,c\mid abc=1\rangle$$

Comment: You definitely cannot conclude it is free of rank $3$; for example, take the free group of rank $2$ in $x$ and $y$, and let $a=x$, $b=xy$, and $c=y$. And I suspect you can make it so that $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ is not free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Consider a group with [presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group):  $$\langle a,b,c\mid abc=1\rangle$$

This group can be seen as the free group on any two elements of $a,b,c.$

If you want a non-free group, rather than a group which is not free of rank $3,$ it can be:

$$\langle a,b,c\mid (abc)^2=1\rangle$$